# How to pull out a src value and parse out a ID number with php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api

Im using wordpress and I pass a custom field through. The data ends up looking like this, but it is different urls sometimes:

```
$embed = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/abcde12345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

I am wondering how I can pull the src value out and how to store the text bolded below within that url.

src="//www.youtube.com/embed/**abcde12345**"

I did a search and saw some people recommended using eval() but I tried reading about it and couldn't understand the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$src = array();
preg_match('(src="//www.youtube.com/embed/(.*?)")e', $embed, $src);
echo $src[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/abcde12345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$start = strpos($a, 'src="') + 5; // 5 is the length of the 'src="' string
$end = strpos($a, '"', $start);

var_dump(
substr($a, $start, $end)
);
```